# How to move other uiobjects relatevely when a new view is shown in the main view

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview

I am developing an iPhone app,which contain a page consisting of three `UISwitch`. When the the `UISwitch` is in `On` state the app displays a small view below the switch. This works for all three switches. But the problem is that the small views displayed will overlaps if I switch on two switches at a time. Is there a way to shift all the other view relatevely when those views are displayed..
Thanx in advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of problem is exactly what auto layout is good for. When you add a new object, remove and regenerate your constraints (you may only need to change a couple, depending on what it currently in place), then call `layoutIfNeeded` on the superview. If you do that inside an animation block, it will even animate into the new layout for you.

Comment: Yes iOS 5 cannot use autolayout.

Comment: Well now you have a reason to move to ios6! Do you _really_ need to support 5, for a new app? It's almost 2 years old.

Answer (score 1):

Its a bit late but this may be what you looking for.

[CollapseClick](https://github.com/bennyguitar/CollapseClick)